# How do we make a website appear first in Google Search? Can we control this?

Tags: seo

Any thoughts on how this behavior can be obtained?

Comment: If there was a guaranteed procedure to do it, what would happen if 2 people followed that procedure? There's only one "number one" spot for each search term

Comment: Buy a majority in Google stocks, so you control the company. Then make them appear your website first.

Comment: And I always thought there was no such thing as a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done by SEO (Search engine optimization), not programmatical or any thing...

Answer (score 2):

Try altering what you type into Google.  For instance, if your website is tomsfarmsupplies.com, type `site:tomsfarmsupplies.com` into Google

Comment: I really hope you are joking (Well i know u r!)... U r ryt? :P

Comment: The O.P. said he wanted a way of making his website appear first in Google's search results.  This is a pretty reliable way...  ;)